# How to install properly Alamofire SwiftyJSon and Alamofire-SwiftyJson

Tags: swift, alamofire

Has you can see from my previous questions, I got a lot of trouble parsing JSON Data. After few days of headache with that, I think the best way still to use alamofire/swiftyjson. I also found the alamofire-swiftyjson to let everything working well together.

But I am not sure how to install this three "libraries" together.

I download the whole Alamofire pack inside my project, I add the SwiftyJson.swift in my project and finally download the Alamofire-SwiftyJson in my project.

But when I change my alamofire request with "responseSwiftyJSON" I get an error saying " "Request" does not have a member name "responseSwiftyJSON

```
   Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://mysiteweb.com/app/data/jsonpersodata.php", parameters: ["username": username]).responseSwiftyJSON { (request, response, data, error)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) and [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) to the project. Then you can use Alamofire to request the data from the server and SwiftyJSON for serialization.

### Alamofire 4

```
Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON { response in
    guard let data = response.data else {
        // No data returned
        return
    }

    let json = JSON(data: data)
    print(json)
}
```

### Alamofire 3

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, url).validate().responseJSON { response in
    switch response.result {
    case .Success:
        if let jsonData = response.result.value {
          let json = JSON(jsonData)
          print(json)
        }
    case .Failure(let error):
        print(error)
    }
}
```

### Alamofire 2

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://api.example.com", parameters: ["username" : username])
        .responseJSON { request, response, data, error in

        let swiftyJSONObject = JSON(data: data!)
}
```

Note that you have to unwrap `data` because server may return nothing.